# Improving performance of SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Tags: sql-server, automated-tests

To be able to automate tests, I have written a hook in SpecFlow that restores a database snapshot before every system test. The code is as following:

```
ALTER DATABASE {databaseName}
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE master
GO
RESTORE DATABASE {databaseName} FROM
DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = @snapshotName
GO
ALTER DATABASE {databaseName}
SET MULTI_USER
```

However, the `ALTER DATABASE SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` part takes about 3 seconds every time, which is a lot if you want to run many system tests.

The workaround I have for this problem currently is using a `KILL` script:

```
USE master
GO
DECLARE @Spid INT
DECLARE @ExecSQL VARCHAR(255)
 
DECLARE KillCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT  DISTINCT SPID
FROM    MASTER..SysProcesses
WHERE   DBID = DB_ID('{databaseName}')
 
OPEN    KillCursor
 
-- Grab the first SPID
FETCH   NEXT
FROM    KillCursor
INTO    @Spid
 
WHILE   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET     @ExecSQL = 'KILL ' + CAST(@Spid AS VARCHAR(50))
 
        EXEC    (@ExecSQL)
 
        -- Pull the next SPID
        FETCH   NEXT 
        FROM    KillCursor 
        INTO    @Spid  
    END
 
CLOSE   KillCursor
 
DEALLOCATE  KillCursor
```

This is fast, but it is not pretty. Does anybody have a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: You can't really make `SET SINGLE_USER` any faster. The RDBMS needs to not only terminate any existing connections, but rollback any outstanding transactions; some of those can be quite large and take a "hot second" to do. Though, I wouldn't really say 3 seconds is a huge amount of time, really.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? SQL 2019 introduced Accelerated Database Recovery.

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case I didn't intend to have any active SQL-connections. It turned out that adding a "SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()" call to a C#-app which used the db, made "SET SINGLE USER" become very fast.